# spread to wide dataframe group by multiple variables in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot-table, tidyr, spread

I was trying to reshape my data from long to wide format using `pivot_wider()` and `spread()` function. Is it possible to spread to wide dataframe group by multiple variables, i.e ccode and year in my dataframe?

current dataframe:

| ccode | industry | year | TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | agri | 2000 | 8.3 |
| 2 | agri | 2001 | 9.2 |
| 2 | mineral | 2000 | 9.1 |
| 3 | agri | 2000 | 6.1 |
| 3 | agri | 2001 | 8.1 |
| 3 | mineral | 2000 | 9 |
| 4 | agri | 2000 | 9 |
| 4 | agri | 2001 | 5.3 |
| 4 | mineral | 2000 | 8.1 |
| 5 | agri | 2000 | 8.4 |
| 5 | agri | 2001 | 4.3 |
| 5 | mineral | 2000 | 4.2 |

ideal result:

| ccode | year | agri | mineral |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2000 | 8.3 | 9.1 |
| 2 | 2001 | 9.2 | NA |
| 3 | 2000 | 6.1 | 9 |
| 3 | 2001 | 8.1 | NA |
| 4 | 2000 | 9 | 8.1 |
| 4 | 2001 | 5.3 | NA |
| 5 | 2000 | 8.4 | 9.1 |
| 5 | 2001 | 4.3 | 4.2 |

Thanks.

Comment: You're not actually spreading the data by multiple variables—the only one you're using to create column names is industry. Should just be a simple use-case for `spread` or `pivot_wider`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `pivot_wider`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_wider(df1, names_from = industry, values_from = TO)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
#  ccode  year  agri mineral
#  <int> <int> <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     2  2000   8.3     9.1
#2     2  2001   9.2    NA  
#3     3  2000   6.1     9  
#4     3  2001   8.1    NA  
#5     4  2000   9       8.1
#6     4  2001   5.3    NA  
#7     5  2000   8.4     4.2
#8     5  2001   4.3    NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ccode = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L), industry = c("agri", "agri", "mineral", "agri", 
"agri", "mineral", "agri", "agri", "mineral", "agri", "agri", 
"mineral"), year = c(2000L, 2001L, 2000L, 2000L, 2001L, 2000L, 
2000L, 2001L, 2000L, 2000L, 2001L, 2000L), TO = c(8.3, 9.2, 9.1, 
6.1, 8.1, 9, 9, 5.3, 8.1, 8.4, 4.3, 4.2)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```